# Function which takes a pthread as input and suspends it

Tags: c, pthreads, real-time, xenomai, preempt-rt

I'm trying to port the real time Thread_Metric from ExpressLogic in POSIX, in order to benchmark PREEMPT_RT patches for Linux, Xenomai and RTAI for my thesis. They provide a C source file with the following functions, which you have to implement in order for the benchmark to work:

```
void   tm_initialize(void (*test_initialization_function)(void));
int    tm_thread_create(int thread_id, int priority, void (*entry_function)(void));
int    tm_thread_resume(int thread_id);
int    tm_thread_suspend(int thread_id);
void   tm_thread_relinquish(void);
void   tm_thread_sleep(int seconds);
int    tm_queue_create(int queue_id);
int    tm_queue_send(int queue_id, unsigned long *message_ptr);
int    tm_queue_receive(int queue_id, unsigned long *message_ptr);
int    tm_semaphore_create(int semaphore_id);
int    tm_semaphore_get(int semaphore_id);
int    tm_semaphore_put(int semaphore_id);
int    tm_memory_pool_create(int pool_id);
int    tm_memory_pool_allocate(int pool_id, unsigned char **memory_ptr);
int    tm_memory_pool_deallocate(int pool_id, unsigned char *memory_ptr);
```

Right now I'm trying to implement the tm_thread_suspend and tm_thread_resume functions, which take a pthread as input. I know that you can suspend a pthread with pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_cond_wait routines, but you have to call these from the thread start_function. I'm new at this kind of stuff and I'm way in over my head. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_suspend` really seems the way to go if it's available. This solution might be more dirty than it's worth. For each thread keep a `semaphore`. Make each thread listen for signals. In the signal handler simply do a `down` on the associated semaphore.

So when you want to `stop` a thread, simply send it a signal (perhaps using a real-time signal would be best) and it will stop in the handler. The handler masks itself by default (that is, it won't be called again if the same signal is received before it is done). When you want to restart the thread, simply do an `up` on the semaphore.

Caveat:

- **Use what @bmargulies suggested, it's better (safer, cleaner, more efficient) if you can**
- You can also use a mutex instead of a semaphore
- Dealing with signals is a nasty job. Before embarking make sure you (re)read about

  - async-signal-safety
  - threads and signals
  - interrupting and restarting system calls (`SA_RESTART`)
- I am pretty sure **[`sem_wait(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait)** isn't async-signal safe, but it's safe as long as you **don't use `SA_NODEFER`** (not that you'd have any reason)

Unfortunately I can't find any really stellar free documentation about this. Still, stellar or not, there is a lot of free documentation.

**Edit**

As suggested by @R.. there are `async-signal-safe` functions that block that you could use (instead of the unsafe `sem_wait`). Here's [a list of functions you may safely use](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html).

Comment: You have the right approach, but need async-signal-safe functions in the signal handler. My answer sketches out some ideas.

Comment: @R.. That is a great idea. I can see `SUSv3` specifies `pselect(2)` as async-signal-safe which would solve the issues with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations of pthreads have these functions. http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3t/pthread_suspend/ But your linux kernel may not support them.

Comment: `pthread_suspend` is not a pthread function, it's some vendor extension.

Comment: 'pthread_suspend() and pthread_continue() were developed by X/Open.'

Comment: And yet not included in the standard. You can probably dig through the rationale documents and find a pretty good reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this completely portably (avoiding all issues with async-signal-unsafe functions) using two signals:

The "thread suspend" signal handler would use `pselect` to atomically unblock the second signal and sleep indefinitely. The second signal would terminate the `pselect` and cause the signal handler to return.

Also there are plenty of other solutions using async-signal-safe interfaces - basically anything that deals with file descriptors and blocking on them rather than on user-space synchronization primitives. For example, having the signal handler `read` from a pipe and writing a single byte to the pipe to resume the thread would work.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this is to use sigwait() and pthread_kill.

// global variable

```
int _fSigSet;
```

Before calling pthread_create we set a signal mask.  Every thread will inherit the mask.  You could set the mask in the thread function I suppose.  Here is the code we use:

```
sigemptyset(&_fSigSet);
sigaddset(&_fSigSet, SIGUSR1);
sigaddset(&_fSigSet, SIGSEGV);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &_fSigSet, NULL);
... 
pthread_create(&Thread, NULL, ThreadProc, NULL);
...
```

**To SUSPEND:**

```
int nSig;  // signal you get if you care.
sigwait(&_fSigSet, &nSig);  // thread is suspended here waiting for signal.
```

**To RESUME:**

```
pthread_kill(&Thread, SIGUSR1);
```

If you cant use SIGUSR1 for some reason be aware that not all signals work for us. We may be doing something wrong, but SIGCONT doesn't work.

We have benchmarked pausing threads this way and this method was 5x faster than using mutexes and condition variables.

Here is some [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635362/max-thread-per-process-in-linux/5643379#5643379) that uses this technique.